# Change selects to a value when an option on other select is selected

Tags: jquery

I've multiple selects with the same numbers between 0 and 10. The values 1 to 10 must be unique, so when the user choose an option already selected on another select, I want the another switch to the 0 value with a trigger on the change event that call an update in db.

I've already try some approches like

```
$("select option[value="+pos+"]").not("#"+id+" option").val(0).change();
```

Where pos is the value and id the id of the select the user just change (so must stay with this value).
But all the attempts not seems to work for now.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally find what I need, thanks to the orientation of Arun P Johny :)

Here is the code

```
$("select:has(option[value="+pos+"]:selected)").not("#"+id).val(0).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/8gY5p/5/

```
<select>
    <option value="0">option 0</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="0">option 0</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="0">option 0</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>

$('select').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    if(value!=0)
        $('select').not(this)
            .has("[value=" + value + "]:selected").val(0).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value to the `select` element, not to the option

```
$("select").not("#"+id).has('[value=" + pos + "]:selected').val(0).change();
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, but how can you search for the selects with a specific value selected (the same the user just select) with this approach ?